# Slide object straight forward when object is facing a arbitrary direction i.e diagonal

Tags: animation, objects, transform-orientation

[image]I'm having trouble figuring out how to slide an object straight out of it's socket when it's at an angle due to being on a cylinder. I have cubes that rotate around a cylinder and when the cubes come to a stop one of the cubes slides out a little. I posted a picture to better help illustrate what i mean & trying to accomplish. When i try to slide it straight out it becomes skewed and moves more up and left instead of straight..[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the transform orientation to Normal and move it on the according scale.
[image]

Also, you can select 'Individual Origins' and move them all at once across their own normal.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i tried that :[. I even tried parenting it to another object and moving the that object on it's axis still not getting th eresults i want.

Answer (score 0):

I see what the problem was. I didn't notice the button for the widget itself[image]